# How to run java class via shellexecute (visual studio c++/mfc)

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to run a java application via `ShellExecute`.

**My Attempt:**

```
ShellExecute(
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              _T("cmd.exe"), 
              _T("/k C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\java -cp    C:\\Users\\aGer\\workspace\\IEC60870\\bin main.CApp 127.0.0.1 -p 2404"), 
              NULL, 
              SW_SHOWNORMAL
);
```

But this command yield an error:

> The command "C:\Program" is either written wrong or could not be
>   found

Why?

Comment: Wrap your path `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\java` with quotes `"`

Comment: When I wrap my path with quotes I get an error: Expect ")"

Comment: It worked in a different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *quote* your path because of spaces between which separate arguments in the command line.

Comment: But this doesn't work, as I mentioned in the above comment. You have to add `\" ..path..\"`.

Comment: What doesn't work? I answered similar as you, just added the note about spaces in command lines -.-

Comment: Only quotation doesn't work here, i.e.
`_T("/k " C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre-\\bin\\java"  ")`..

Comment: That's obvious, i dare to guess the questioner knows this C basic (escaping quotes in strings) :/ The real problem was this space between *Program* and *Files*.

Comment: I guess you're right, but for me it wasn't obvious. :(

Comment: No clue, why this got downvoted. It gives a concise solution to the problem. It is to be expected, that the OP does know at least the **basics** of C programming. Apparently this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for a solution. Just simply add `\" ..path..\"`, i.e.:

`ShellExecute(
              NULL, 
              NULL, 
              _T("cmd.exe"), 
              _T("/k \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\java\" -cp    C:\\Users\\aGer\\workspace\\IEC60870\\bin main.CApp 127.0.0.1 -p 2404"), 
              NULL, 
              SW_SHOWNORMAL
);`